# What happens to locals if they're referenced by an anonymous function called after they fall out of scope?

Tags: c#, scope, anonymous-function

Consider this contrived example:

```
public static class Test {

    private static List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
    private static Int32 _foo = 123;

    public static void Foo() {

        Int32       foo = _foo += 123;
        Object      bar = new Object();
        IDisposable baz = GetExpensiveObject();

        Action callback = new Action(delegate() {

            DoSomething( foo, bar, baz );

            baz.Dispose();
        });

        foo = 456;
        bar = new Object();

        actions.Add( callback );
    }

    public static void Main() {

        Foo();
        Foo();

        foreach(Action a in actions) a();
    }
}
```

Looking at `Main`, supposing that `Foo` is called twice, and the contents of `actions` (by now, 2 `Action` instances) are executed afterwards, what is the state of the variables `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` within `callback`?

And if `callback` is never called, will `baz` *ever* be disposed (because of the reference contained within `callback` contained within `actions`?), and what is `actions.Clear()` is called, will `baz` be disposed of then?

(I'm not at a computer with a compiler or IDE on for me to test)

Comment: You're at a computer with internet access, so you have access to an IDE: http://ideone.com/

Answer (score 1):

Well, remind that the lifetime of local variables will be extended for the lifetime of anonymous methods if they are used there. That doesn't mean the the values of the variables are copied at the point of creating the anonymous methods. So "DoSomething" will be called everytime with "456" and the second created object.

You can check it if you create a new WinForms-Project, place a new button at the form and add the following code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 123;

        this.button1.Click += (Lsender, Le) => { MessageBox.Show(i.ToString()); };

        i = 456;
    }
```

Please take care of reference types here, because if you would write

```
{
private static Foo(object value)
{
    object bar = value;
    //...
}

private static void Main()
{
    object obj = new object();

    Foo(obj);
    Foo(obj);

    //...
}
```

}

In that case each callback will have its own variable "bar" but each of them are refering to the same object in heap memory.

Answer (score 1):

The anonymous methods will be rewritten by the compiler to hold a reference to the same memory area *on the heap* as the local scope. The garbage collector will find this reference active, and will not garbage collect the target until the anonymous methods are also collected.

However... what if you're not allocating on the heap, but on the stack which may be overwritten by new method calls? ;)

```
private static void Main(String[] args) {
    var rng = CreateRNG();
    Console.WriteLine(rng());
    Console.WriteLine(rng());
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static unsafe Func<Int32> CreateRNG() {
    var v = stackalloc Int32[1];
    v[0] = 4;
    return () => v[0];
}
```

This code prints 4 for the first invocation, and a semi-random number the second time.

The real code, extracted using Reflector and cleaned up by hand, and with methods renamed so they will compile (the compiler uses special characters like <> in automatically generated method names):

```
private static unsafe Func<Int32> CreateRNG() {
    Int32* numPtr = stackalloc Int32[1];

    var class2 = new __c__DisplayClass1();
    class2.v = numPtr;
    class2.v[0] = 4;
    return new Func<Int32>(class2._CreateRNG_b__0);
}

[CompilerGenerated]
public sealed class __c__DisplayClass1 {
    public unsafe Int32* v;

    public unsafe Int32 _CreateRNG_b__0() {
        return v[0];
    }
}
```

This shows that the compiler rewrites the anonymous method into a new function, in this case in a new class to hold any referenced local values. The class is not needed if there are no needs to keep local references.

And I can also guess that the first invocation works because we call the returned `Func<Int32>` and it reads the value easily. The method body is very small, it can probably be inlined. The value, 4, is passed to `Console.WriteLine`, and that method call is probably overwriting the stack (or a method call that `Console.WriteLine` in turn does), changing the value that the pointer points to.